# No overload for method `CharacterSave' takes `1' arguments

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got this error when I upgraded my project to the newest Unity version..

Don't know which part am I wrong . But here's my snips of my code

**CharacterModule.cs**

```
var prefab = Instantiate(characterData).GetComponent<Player>();
prefab.name = characterName;
prefab.account = user.Username;
prefab.className = request.ClassName;
prefab.transform.position = gameConfig.startPosition;
prefab.health = prefab.healthMax;
prefab.mana = prefab.manaMax;
Database.CharacterSave(prefab);
Destroy(prefab.gameObject);

var gameUser = GameUserModule.Database.Get(user.Username);
if (gameUser == null)
{
```

**GameMapnetwork.cs**

```
        // add to client
    NetworkServer.AddPlayerForConnection(connection, go, 0);
}

public void SaveCharacters()
{
    if (!NetworkServer.active)
        return;

    Database.CharacterSaveMany(Player.onlinePlayers.Values.ToList());
}

public void SaveCharacter(Player player)
{
    Database.CharacterSave(player);
}
```

**GameModule.cs**

```
var go = Database.CharacterLoad(name, GameConfig.Instance.GetPlayerClasses());
if (go == null)
{
    message.Respond("Character not found", ResponseStatus.Failed);
    return;
}
var player = go.GetComponent<Player>();

var gameUser = gameUserDatabase.Get(user.Username);
if (gameUser == null)
{
    gameUser = GameUserModule.Database.CreateObject(user.Username);
    gameUserDatabase.Insert(gameUser);
}
gameUser.SelectedCharacter = name;
gameUserDatabase.Update(gameUser);

string resultMap = player.savedCurrentMap;
Vector3 resultPosition = player.transform.position;

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(resultMap))
{
    resultMap = player.savedCurrentMap = GameConfig.Instance.startScene;
    resultPosition = player.transform.position = GameConfig.Instance.startPosition;
    Database.CharacterSave(player);
}

Destroy(player.gameObject);

if (mapCallback != null)
    mapCallback(resultMap, resultPosition);
```

Here's some body of my code. I don't know which part is wrong. I am really appreciate you help!

Comment: Welcome, please share more of your code, not just that part. At least show the part where you are defining and initialising player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically that error you mention is telling you that you haven't define a method called CharacterSave with a single parameter in its parameter list. Something like:

```
CharacterSave(paramType paramName)
```

You should show us where you implement the method:

```
CharacterSave(...)
```

It could also be you just mixed names with the overloaded method SaveCharacters:

```
SaveCharacters()
SaveCharacter(Player player)
```

Comment: thanks got it , i set my CharacterSave(player, true) , thanks alot now its fixed.